# Eclipse debug issue with class Java API in rt.jar

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, decompiler

I have a problem with Eclipse Debug. First of all, the steps that I performed is the follows:

- I installed Eclipse Photon
- I installed the Eclipse Color Theme plugin
- I updated the settings of formatting
- I installed the Enhanced Class Decompiler plugin.

I have configured last plugin editing only File Associations setting the Class Decompiler Viewer as Default for file types both .class and .class without source.

Now it happen that if I open a class of Java API as SimpleFormatter in rt.jar, the decompiler show me the source code decompiled (which I know is just representation based on decompiler used, in my case I use JD-Core). However, I can't to apply any breakpoint on this code, So I can't debug this class, which I know it is used. I can't even to put breakpoints on class method.
I before could to put breakpoints, but it gave me an error like "Unable to install breakpoint..." when I ran debug.

Specifically, I would like to debug the classes source code in the Java API's jar files, for example, debug the previous class. Do you know how I can do this?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

The jars contained in the JRE are compiled without debug info, that means that the debugger doesn't have any information about the line executed.
If you want to debug the classes contained in that jar, you have to download the sources and compile it with "-g" option

Comment: Or use the JDK.

Comment: absolute @nitind

Comment: Ok it's good. So I have to replace, for example, the rt.jar file with one that I compiled to debug? Since these are classes that are part of the Java API, how do I replace those classes?

Comment: you can replace the jar file or, as nitid said, you can use the jdk instead of the jre. The same jars in the jdk are compiled with -g options, so you can use it for debugging.

Comment: How I replace the JRE with JDK?

Comment: in eclipse you can configure the jdk in window>preferences>java>installed jre. Then configure your runtime to use the jdk.

Comment: I configured the JDK for installed JRE. Then I opened the Java Build Path of the project and in it I selected JDK for the JRE System Library. Despite these steps I still cannot assign breakpoints into Java API classes. Is there anything else I have to do?

Comment: Add: JRE System Library (JDK 8u172) is visible also in Project Explorer.

Comment: There are no solutions for this?

Answer (score 0):

I have found out that it's a bug which occurs for latest versions of Eclipse. Specifically, a bug among Eclipse and Enanched Class Decompiler. I solved using a previous version of Eclispe.